# Detecting one specific object from a video

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, image-recognition, yolo

This is what we are trying to achieve.

Given the following conditions:

- there is a specific object, say a coin
- you have that physical coin and you can take as many pictures as you like of that 1 coin.
- the coin is present in a video clip

How can we best detect the position and timecode of that coin within the video clip?

Is it possible to use Yolov3 for this? I think yolo does not work well when training just one class of objects and with a limited range of training images.

Is there a better way?

Comment: yolo works well for a single class. Just take as many images of that coin as possible, with different backgrounds/illumination/etc. + as many images without that coin, as possible. What is the timecode of the coin?

Comment: depends on the complexity of the  problem.  if you are looking at a coin  from 10meter away. then yolo will not help you . you need to go for some raw traditional cv blob based algorithm. if you are looking at the coin from 10cm to 1m. then yolo will give you good result.  Cheers